# grammar environment and colored keyword

Tags: beamer, color, mdwtools

I did define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

and tried

```
\begin{grammar}
   stepsScript ::= \keyword{steps} \synt{steps} \keyword{steps}
\end{grammar}
```

and I get the message:

> Argument of @declaredcolor has an extra }

My `\keyword` command works fine outside `grammar`. Omitting `\textcolor` results in a boldface `\keyword` within the `grammar` environment, as expected. But what do I have to do to get a boldface red coloured keyword?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might have a look at the `listings` package, which can highlight keywords.

Comment: Could you please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the bug? The error is probably in a part of the code you haven't shown here.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I tried to complete the code you provided with the `syntax` package in the `article` documentclass then I got a different error, `Use of \gr@implitem doesn't match its definition` at the start of `stepsScript`. However, adding `<>` brackets around that term works, including color. Can you confirm if the code below works for you?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{syntax}
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
<stepsScript> ::= \keyword{steps} \synt{steps} \keyword{steps}
\end{grammar}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks Marijn, but in combination with the beamer class the code does not work for me.

Comment: Then how about you provide a complete minimal example, including everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that is necessary to reproduce your issue, but nothing unnecessary? This way we could really help you instead of doing guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beamer` class redefines the color commands `\textcolor` and `\color`. This causes an issue with the `syntax` package. As a workaround you can use the original definition that uses `\@declaredcolor` directly in your new command. Because `\@declaredcolor` contains an `@` symbol you need to surround the definition with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{syntax}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{\@declaredcolor{red}#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Syntax with color in beamer}
\begin{grammar}
<stepsScript> ::= \keyword{steps} \synt{steps} \keyword{steps}
\end{grammar}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great! Dankeschön

To be honest! It took another two days to get your solution working with lualatex and my new beamertheme for my company.